# Usage of "make up my mind"

Tags: word-usage

Can "made up my mind be used" in context like:

> I made up my mind about quitting smoking.

I am being persuaded that *resolved* should be used instead, but it seems to me that both versions are correct but differ in a level of resolution of speaker.

Comment: I'd use present perfect: _I **have made up my mind** about quitting smoking_ => _I've made up my mind about quitting smoking_ (this suggests that you've struggled a bit with the idea) or _I've resolved to quit smoking_. I think there's not much difference beyond register between _resolve_ (more formal) & _make up one's mind_. Both involve a decision to quit smoking, & regardless of the words used to express that decision, your actions & not your rhetoric will show your level of resolution. Been there & done that often enough to know. Made it stick in 1975 after 20 years of puffing away.

Comment: Every now and then you will find that there is more than a single way to express a concept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are not sure about a certain usage of a phrase, it is good to use corpora such as
[Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) to find out how the phrase is being used in novels, magazine articles, etc.

In this scenario, it is not wrong to use *make up my mind* since [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/make?q=make%20up%20my%20mind#make__75) suggests that it has the definition:

> **make up one's mind**
>
> make a decision; decide: He made up his mind to attend the meeting.

and COCA shows that the phrase *make up my mind about something* has actually been used though a better way to write it would be

> I made up my mind *to* quit smoking.

The word *resolve* has the meaning

> **resolve**
>
> decide *firmly* on a course of action

so if you want express that *I am determined to quit smoking* then *resolve* is a better word.

And yes, it would be better to write it this way:

> I resolved to quit smoking.

Comment: Going back to OP's example, the exact phrasing would probably be "I *made* up my mind to quit smoking" - past tense - since the phrase refers to a past decision not to the process of making decision.

Comment: @amacy Yeah, I agree. When OP mentioned the word *resolve*, it was in past tense too. Seems like I would have to edit my question a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I know about COCA/BNC, I even found phrase "You’re old enough to  make  your  own mind up  about smoking." in LDOCE examples, I simply have to persuade good language specialist who is very hard to persuade in rare cases she is wrong :). P.S.Edited tense in question.

Comment: @elevener Cool! Good luck then :) Don't worry about the past tense I've edited.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both seem to be correct in this context. Though "make up my mind" would suggest you had conflicting opinions within yourself and you had to spend quite some time deciding on which.
"Resolve" seems to suggest a decision without having spent much time with different sides of the matter.